# Is it possible to solve the following equation without using the Rational Root Theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, roots, factoring

Given $f(x)=x^4+2x^3+2x^2-2x-3$, where $x-1$ is a factor of $f(x)$, how is it possible to solve $f(x)$ without the Rational Root Theorem?

Here's my progress:
$$f(x)=x^4+2x^3+2x^2-2x-3$$
$$f(x)=(x-1)(x^3+3x^2-5x+3)$$

And there's where I got stuck.
I cheated, though, and tried solving this equation with the Rational Root Theorem. That's what I got:
$$f(x)=x^4+2x^3+2x^2-2x-3$$
$$f(x)=(x-1)(x^3+3x^2-5x+3)$$
$$f(x)=(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+2x+3)$$
$$f(x)=(x-1)(x+1)(x-(-1-\sqrt2))(x-(-1+\sqrt2))$$

Please, if you're answering this question, I'd really appreciate if you could explain your procedures and what technique you used.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is Descartes' Rule of Signs also off limits?

Comment: Here, RRT says that the possible rational roots of the equation are $\pm1$ and $\pm3$. When tested, $-1$ and $1$ are found to be roots, while neither $3$ nor $-3$ is a root. Thus, besides $1$ and $-1$, all roots of the equation are either irrational or non-real.

Comment: Sometimes you can get lucky with carefully doing grouping to factor.

Comment: Often the roots will be "nice enough" to do by hand/inspection. Check the integers between $-3$ and $3$. This is often where some of the roots will be (at least in a quiz/exam situation where getting the roots is part of the purpose of the problem)

Answer (score 5):

$$\begin{aligned}
x^4+2x^3+2x^2-2x-3
&=(x^4+2x^2-3)+(2x^3-2x) \\
&=(x^2+3)(x^2-1)+2x(x^2-1) \\
&=(x^2-1)(x^2+3+2x) \\
&=(x^2-1)(x^2+2x+3)
\end{aligned}$$